# How To Get The Largest Sum From An Array With Iteration Funcrtion?

Tags: javascript

Hello Every one i want to solve this problem with javascript and es6 the problem is
if i have an array like that [1,2,3,4]  so i want to check every probability like the following and return the greatest number

```
1--> (1*2) + (3*4) = 14
2--> (1*3) + (2*4) = 11
3--> (1*4) + (2*3) = 10
```

then the greatest number is 14 as a return result ---> how can i do that using function and keep in mind if the array have 100 number how can i do the 99 probabilities dynamically 
notes : maybe the array is not sorted and it may be an odd not only even thank u

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like you're asking us to do the work for you...

Comment: My presumption is that the first one (sorted) is always the largest.

Comment: @Stephan Good spot! I'd love to see it as an full answer.

Comment: for [1,2,3,4,5,6] should it test `1*2 + 3*4 + 5*6` (and combinations)?

Comment: and tried to solve it of course but i didn't get the logic for it so i asked here programmers aren't lazy , any way thank u @jakerella

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? And why are you depending on using JS?

Comment: @Stephan i'm trying to calculate the bigger value of all combination like that for [1,2,3,4,5,6] it should test 1*2 + 3*4 + 5*6 (and combinations) but  always as u said the greater value is the first sorted one so could u please try to write a simple code for a beginner and i'm using js or es6 because i want to go deep in front end development

Comment: I already posted my answer/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying the largest numbers with each other results in a larger sum than multiplying a large number with a low number and then sum them up (compare given a circumference a square is the rectangle with the largest surface area). One therefore only has to calculate `[0]*[1] + [2]*[3] + [4]*[5] + ...`
(assuming that the array length is even):

```
const array = [4,2,1,3].sort();
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2)
  sum += array[i - 1] * array[i];
```

Edit: For that calculation with consecutive numbers starting from 1 one doesn't even need JS, the closed form for the sum is `1/3 * (n - 1)(4*n² - 5*n)` (with n being the largest (even) number).

Comment: You could add more details, like that the first combination (sorted) will be always greatest. +1

Comment: I think you assumed that the length of the array is always even which might not be true.

Comment: The problem is that the question is lacking information on how to group the numbers. The way I interpreted the question having an odd length is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Stephen, Multiplying the largest numbers with each other results in a larger sum than multiplying a large number with a low number and then sum them up. And also you should be multiplying consecutive numbers in the array like (1*2)+(3*4)+(5*6)+...+(99*100)etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the combinations.
Mathematically, you will always yield the highest values by multiplying the highest available numbers.
So, it would be pointless to multiply an high number with anything other then the second highest number.

```
const arr = [4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 7]
let sum = arr.sort().reduce((sum, val, idx) => sum += (idx % 2 !== 0) ? arr[idx - 1] * arr[idx] : 0 , 0)
```

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed the function above will handle both even or uneven arrays, albeit it's your choice if you'd rather have an "even only" function for whatever reason

Comment: thank u for your answer, could u please explain the code because i don't understand its logic

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed I added a few comments, if something is unclear let me know

Comment: thank u but can u please explain the part of foreach again with fully explain of if statements sorry if i'm stupid because i'm new in this field

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed it's ok man. I can try, altho some of it you should look up javascript documentations.
sort function takes a callback, which defines the sort order you want. 
(a, b) => a < b is a callback to sort the array descending.
To take an action every two values, we use (idx+1) % 2 === 0, which evaluates if the current index in the array is divisible by 2. If the array is uneven, the last segment if (idx == len - 1) will be called because the last index is not divisible by 2.

Comment: @MohammedSaberMohammed for a better sort explanation, theres one in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Comment: If the calculation is about pairs it is mathematically pointless to just add the remaining number in case of an odd length. It would be as (if not more) justified to for example return zero. Therefore you could eliminate your sort parameter and the last if.

Comment: one another question is it matter if we sort them ascending instead of descending because i noticed the value is changing if the array is odd so if i have [1,2,3,4,5] and i sort them descending the result is 27 otherwise is 19 or the sorting is up to me

Comment: @Stephan you're right, unless that uneven case was explicitly requested (which was not). I guess it depends on what's the intention of the function, but Mohammed already said it will only be even arrays, so there we go.
MohammedSaberMohammed, the different result you got from the sorting was because it was an uneven array. Any even array will always return the same value for either ascending or descending